# In-house app distribution for client with my apple ID

Tags: ios

We are developing an iOS app for a client which they are planning to distribute inside their company using in-house distribution profile.

They have shared the distribution certificate, private key and provisioning profile with us. 
I have enrolled to iOS Developer Enterprise Program.
Question is - Do I need to enroll to client's iOS Developer Enterprise Program before I can use their certificate and profile to generate the IPA file which they can distribute in-house to their company.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure but try installing their certificate and private key in your keychain and then installing the provisioning profile and check if you can chose it in the Build Settings Code Signing section. If you can set it for Release version and have the Archive Scheme configured to use Release then you should be good.

If not and you cannot enroll into their program you can always build the archive with your cert and provisioning profile and then resign the app using the command line `codesign` tool. Just pay attention not to break the embedded entitlements that xcode puts there. Use `-d` option to check what they are originally.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to build an Enterprise in house app is the distribution certificate including private key, the provisioning profile and the according bundle identifier.